# customizing breadcrumb in sharepoint using ParentLevelsDisplayed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, page-layout, pages, breadcrumb

I am trying to hide the root level alone in the breadcrumb

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"> 
<SharePointWebControls:ListSiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="CurrentNavigation" 
 RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" ParentLevelsDisplayed="0"  /><br /> </asp:Content>
```

Now if i give `ParentLevelsDisplayed=0`,  its showing only the current page in `breadcrumb`, if its 1 it is showing 1 parent and so on.

Now how can i remove only the root parent and show all other parents?

I.E 
If i have it like

```
Somesite -> Home -> Schools -> Montessori
```

I want to display

```
Home -> Schools -> Montessori
```

Comment: Try setting HideInteriorRootNodes = "false"
if no success see if you can do something with RootNodeStyle

Comment: tried HideInteriorRootNodes but no luck
the root node is still coming

Comment: is it possible to apply rootnodestyle only to the root element?

Comment: Please apply some style to observe where it is taking affect.

Comment: Are you fine with any JavaScript to hide it run time?

Comment: Yeah if there is no other way to configure it through sharepoint configuration

Answer (score 1):

If in case you are unable to find any OOB solution, and ready to use some jQuery then I think it can be achieved in below steps.

**1.** First surround your breadcrumb control in master page with a div container, this help in catching on run time.

*Your Code*

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"> 
  <SharePointWebControls:ListSiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="CurrentNavigation" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" ParentLevelsDisplayed="0"  />
</asp:Content>
```

*Suggestion in Code*

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"> 
  <div id="UniqueID">
    <SharePointWebControls:ListSiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="CurrentNavigation" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" ParentLevelsDisplayed="0"  />
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**2.** When you investigate your breadcrumb's rendered html using developer tool, it will be noticed that the breadcrumb is contained in `span`

```
<div id="UniqueID">
    <span id="ctl00_Sitemappath1" hideinteriorrootnodes="true" sitemapproviders="SPContentMapProvider">
        <a href="#ctl00_Sitemappath1_SkipLink">
            <img width="0" height="0" style="border-width: 0px;" alt="Skip Navigation Links src="/WebResource.axd?d=cgjLuuzo9laIDKrNp8K9dB_rjEQ2imaJ-OLdUpvi6j9SAwQkLmpz1KPsYL4jBzZx3s7Hhmd0ib4Sjv8Y8VX6IdQFPAEZR0BOJ9_cI-NuOoU1&amp;t=635201010537823876">
        </a>
        <span>
            <a title="Some title" href="/Pages/default.aspx">Some Site</a>
        </span>
        <span> 
            &gt; 
        </span>
        <span>
            <a title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" href="/Some Site/Pages/default.aspx">Some Sub Site</a>
        </span>
        <span> 
            &gt; 
        </span>                                                                                                                                 
    </span>
</div>
```

**Note**: Since your are using `ListSiteMapPath` control, rendered html slightly be different.

**3.** If you would want to get rid of `Somesite ->` part of breadcrumb, then we can use below jQuery.

```
//hide Somesite
$("#UniqueID > span > span:first-child").css('display', 'none');
//hide >
$("#UniqueID > span > span:nth-child(2)").css('display', 'none');
```